# Several sites in local in nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, local

If I want to work locally with 3 sites

site1
site2
site3

How do I configure my nginx and host?

sites-available:

```
server_name site1

location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
}
```

The other sites:

server_name site2

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
}
```

server_name site3

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
}
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   site1
127.0.0.1   site2
127.0.0.1   site3
```

This does not work, they take me to the same site

Comment: Why using the proxy pass directive?

Comment: You stated that this configuration is from the directory `sites-available`. On Debian based systems this directory is not included in the configuration, rather `sites-enabled` is. You need to create symlinks to the config files in `sites-available` in the `sites-enabled` directory. Do these symlinks exist?

Comment: oohh I had not created the links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using the `proxy_pass` directive?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site1;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name site1.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site2;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name site2.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 site1.local site2.local
```

see also:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: What makes you think the sites are just basic files and not a different backend server?

Comment: Thank @Marek Lisiecki it worked for me

Comment: @GeraldSchneider becouse Isaac wrote "If I want to work locally with 3 sites" he doesn't meant about reverse proxy ;)